# R timestamp after function has already run

Tags: r, timestamp

I had something running last night so left my machine running over night. Ran Sys.time() after such that it would timestamp when the operation finished. However, in a rush, I wrote sys.time() which isn't a function!

I'm using R studio which has a history window and thought surely there must be a way thats not too difficult to find a timestamp for my most recent operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did some digging and found in:

```
C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Rstudio-Desktop
```

There is a file called `history_database`

Opened it in a text reader, went to the bottom, found the number and then used an online Epoch & Unix timestamp conversion tool.

in R you could read the file then use:

```
(as.POSIXct(n/1000, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

Where `n` is your timestamp number from the file. My result was is BST.

Might be an easier way, but this may help others so thought I'd answer rather than delete the question.